# Why do I need to "fftshift" the product of DFTs to recover the convolution product

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fft

I need to compute a convolution product using the convolution theorem. However, I do not understand why I neeed to apply `fftshift` on the inverse fourier transform to get the correct result. Otherwise, the result is swapped (well, I know that is what fftshift is made for, but I don't understand why I obtain a swapped result from the inverse fft). Here is a minimal example with two functions that decrease quickly so that I do not add to bother with padding. The result is checked against `scipy.signal.convolve`:

```
    import numpy as np
    import scipy.signal as sig

    Nx = 400
    xp = np.arange(Nx) - Nx/2.
    Lg = 20
    Lb = 25

    ff = np.exp(-(xp/Lg)**2) * xp/Lg    # function (two bumps of opposite signs)
    gg = np.zeros(Nx)                   # convolution kernel (just a box)
    gg[abs(xp)<Lb] = 1

    conv_pure = sig.convolve(ff, gg, mode="same")  # that is the correct one

    tff = np.fft.rfft(ff)             # DFT of the function
    tfg = np.fft.rfft(gg)             # DFT of the kernel

    conv_dfts = np.fft.irfft(tff*tfg).real  # should be the convolution product
    conv_dftshift = np.fft.fftshift(conv_dfts)
```

[And here is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PTnX.png)

So, why is `conv_dfts`swapped ?

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the calculations in [`scipy.signal.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve.html) with `mode='full'` or `mode='same'` to be properly defined, the data in the first argument is (effectively) extended with zeros.  Your FFT calculation, on the other hand, does circular convolution, which corresponds to using the periodic extension of the data.  To see the consequences of this difference, consider how the first point of the result is calculated.

(It is helpful to have in mind the usual "sliding window" view of convolution, such as shown at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Visual_explanation.  In your case, the sliding window is `gg`.)

For `scipy.signal.convolve` with `mode='same'`, you can visualize the calculation of the first point by aligning the right half of `gg` over the left end of `ff`, and summing the elementwise product of those two signals.  `ff` is very small at its left end, so this calculation is very close to 0.  Subsequent points of the convolution remain zero until the sliding window starts encountering larger values of `ff`. So the "interesting" part of the result is in the middle of the convolution.

For the first point of the FFT calculation, imagine the right end of `gg` aligned with the left end of `ff`.  Again take the sum of the elementwise product.  There are two big differences here.  First, `gg` is not shifted by half its length like it is with `mode='same'` in `scipy.signal.convolve`.  Second, the values that `gg` is multiplied by are not all zero--they are the periodic extension of `ff`, so in this "sliding window" visualization, we have the rectangular window aligned directly over the center of the double pulse (in the periodic extension).  Because of the symmetry of `gg` and the antisymmetry of `ff`, this first value is 0.  As `gg` slides right, the symmetry is broken, the positive pulse dominates the calculation, and nontrivial values are computed.  Once the window passes the double pulse, the values of the convolution become very small.  They become very big again near the end of the convolution, when the rectangular pulse encounters the other side of the double pulse.

To get your FFT calculcation to match `scipy.signal.convolve` calculation, you can adjust the phase of the rectangular pulse in `gg`.  For example (assuming `Nx` is even).  For example, if you add this line

```
gg2 = np.roll(gg, -(Nx//2 - 1))
```

and use `gg2` in place of `gg` in the calculation of `tfg`:

```
tfg = np.fft.rfft(gg2)             # DFT of the kernel
```

then `conv_dfts` and `conv_pure` agree.  There are others ways you can tweak things to get the results to align as you expected.  The main point of this answer is to explain why the results that you calculated were different.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was enlightening